# Linked-List: read String in C

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I need to read string (line by line) from a file and store them to linked list. I can read from file and print them. However, I have issue how to store them to linked list. I tried to create linked-list and save them like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    char data[256];
    struct node *next;

} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;
node_t *current = NULL;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char temp = 'Hello';
    insertToHead(temp);
    return 0;
}

void insertToHead(char *word) 
{
    node_t *link = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    link->data = strcpy(link->data , word);

    link->next = head;
    head = link;
}
```

Comment: And what's the question ? Besides abusing global variables and not copying the string but only the pointer, your code looks ok so far.

Comment: "it is not working" is not really a very helpful description.

Comment: `strcpy(link->data , c)`. You can't assign to an array..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Same.. diff.c:24:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
  link->data = strcpy(link->data , c);

Comment: You are using `sizeof(struct node_t)` but it should be either `sizeof(struct node)` or `sizeof(node_t)`

Comment: Just call the function, don't assign it's result!

Comment: How do you read the string from the file and how do you call the insert function? Can you modify the question and add this one as well?

Comment: @Svabael For testing purpose I used like that.  
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 char temp = 'hello';
 insertToHead(temp);
 return 0;
}

Comment: @Soulmaster sigh, edit your question instead of posting comments!

Comment: @Soulmaster and please read this:  [MCVE].

Comment: Oh my... I don't know where to begin. Assigning a char with a multi-char? Passing `char` instead of `char*`? the usage of `strcpy`? Please, step back and write something simpler.

Comment: Sorry but the edited code generates 3 compiler warnings and 3 errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues.

I fixed the here and now the program compiles at least:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct node
{
    char data[256];
    struct node *next;

} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;
node_t *current = NULL;

void insertToHead(char *word) 
{
    node_t *link = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    strcpy(link->data , word);

    link->next = head;
    head = link;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *temp = "Hello";
    insertToHead(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

You really should learn how to read the output of your compiler.

Comment: @coder no, it's perfectly correct. `temp` points to the string literal `"Hello"`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz THX man. I am Learning C.  Is it best way to do it ? Or there is better way to Push strings to linked-list

Comment: @MichaelWalz maybe I am missing something but, what if the you don't have enough memory for: char *temp = "Hello"; shouldn't you allocate memory so as to be sure that you will not run out??

Comment: @coder well yes you are missing something here. `char *temp = "Hello";` declares a pointer that points to a (usually non modifiable) string literal, that's all.

Comment: @Soulmaster the algorithm is correct, but there are more elegant ways to do this, especially not having a global variable `head`. Imagine you want to have two different lists in your program. How would you do that ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, one last thing, what is not very clear to me is: by declaring  char *temp ; you declare a pointer pointing somewhere in the memory. With  *temp = "Hello"; is like saying wherever temp points make it's content to be "hello" , but what if we had some other data declared in the same spot (another string which now gets  covered by "hello")? Then what is the purpose of Malloc? isn't it to "ask permission" to allocate safely something in the memeory??

Comment: @coder when you write `char *temp = "Hello`", a string `"Hello"` of fixed length will be somewhere in memory and no other data will be "declared" at that spot of memory ever during the lifetime of the program and `temp` will point initially to that string. `malloc`on the other hand allows you to  allocate a portion of memory who's length is maybe known only at runtime and not during compile time. Read a good C textbook where all this stuff is explained in details.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, so char *temp = "Hello" is different from char *temp ;  *temp = "Hello"; ,which first declares the pointer and we don't know where it is pointing??

Comment: @coder no, `char *temp = "Hello"` is exactly the same thing as `char *temp ; temp = "Hello";`. But `*temp = "Hello"` is wrong, it won't compile.

Comment: @coder ...but. you could write `*temp = 'A'`, which compiles but at run time you'll get undefined behaviour (practically always a crash on any modern systems such as Linux, Windows, MacOS) because string literals cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few syntactic problems and you should include the string library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  char data[256];
  struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *head = NULL;
node_t *current = NULL;

void insertToHead(char *word) {
  node_t *link = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

  strcpy(link->data , word);

  link->next = head;
  head = link;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char *temp = "Hello";

  insertToHead(temp);
  return 0;
}
```

***EDIT***

> I was trying to solve the issue when @MichaelWalz already posted the
>   solution